# Find coordinates of third point in triangle with given coordinates of other two sides and its angles in C

Tags: c, formula, triangulation

Hello i have homework triangulation.c with two watchovers and boat.

I have to find distance of this boat, and her coordinates.

I have coordinates of x1,y1,x2,y2,alpha,beta i know how to calculate distance between watchtowers, distance to boat but not her coordinates

here is code i have

```
float to_radians(const int angle);
float get_watchtowers_distance(const int x1, const int y1, const int x2, const int y2);
float get_boat_distance(const float d, const int alpha, const int beta);

int main() {
    int x1 = 76;
    int y1 = 316;
    int x2 = 57;
    int y2 = 516;
    int alpha = 17;
    int beta = 17;
    float d = get_watchtowers_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2); //200.90
    float b = get_boat_distance(d, alpha, beta); //30.71

    float x3 = ? //97.07
    float y3 = ? //418.90


    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f", b, x3, y3);
    return 1;
}
```

can you help me with some formula to get x3 and y3 coordinates? thank you

[image: image of homework]

Comment: Stack overflow is about programming, not basic math (geometry in your case). What is your programming problem ? Any exception ? Compilation error ? Wrong outputs ?

Comment: Note that: $l_1 + l_2 = l$ and $ tan(alpha) =\frac{d}{l_1}$ and $ tan(beta) = \frac{d}{l_2}$. Hence, $d / tan(\alpha) = l_1$ and $d / tan(\beta) = l_2$. Therefore, $l = \frac{d}{tan(\alpha)} + \frac{d}{tan(\beta)} = d * (\frac{1}{tan(\alpha)} + \frac{1}{tan(\beta)})$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725790/calculate-third-point-of-triangle-from-two-points-and-angles

Comment: [Solving ASA Triangles](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-asa-triangles.html)??